# Open-closed principle VS DRY

Tags: oop

Let's say we had only one payment method in application. We created one interface and one implementation:

```
interface Payment {
   //
}

class InitialPayment implements Payment {
   //
}
```

Later on the product owner asked to add another payment method. We didn't brake the `open-closed principle` and created second implementation:

```
class AnotherPayment implements Payment {
   //
}
```

Everything looks good and let's say everything works fine. But what if these 2 classes have 80% common logic and code? Did we brake `don't repeat yourself` principle?

Or did I miss something?

Comment: Why not refactor the common logic into another class then?

Comment: depending on the language you can have interfaces which implement methods. otherwise you can use mixins https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin

Comment: @NicoHaase Of course we can refactor. But does the open-closed principle without refactoring brake DRY principle? Probably you got my point.